# Not able to make the dropdown opaque with css color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a simple autocomplete. The content on the dropdown is not visible properly. It is transparent and is overlapping with text in the background. Following is my css:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete{
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  cursor: default;
  li {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border-top: solid 1px #DDD;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    a {
      color: white;
      display: block;
      padding: 3px;
    }
    a.ui-state-hover, a.ui-state-active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
  }
}
```

**html.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field :manufacturer_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Manufacturer.order(:name).map(&:name)} %>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#equipment_manufacturer_name').autocomplete({
    source: $('#equipment_manufacturer_name').data('autocomplete-source')
  });
```

Sorry if this is a simple and dumb question but CSS is not my field. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: post a pen or a live code example

Comment: try adding `z-index:100` to `ul.ui-autocomplete` class

Comment: where is you HTML

Comment: Its not exactly html but html.erb. I am coding on rails framework. If needed I can add it to the question. Shall I add it ? @AmiteshKumar

Comment: yes, code for drop down is needed .

Comment: I updated both **html.erb** and **jquery** code. @AmiteshKumar

Comment: I tried adding `z-index:100` to `ul.ui-autocomplete` class no luck. Still the same. @MinalChauhan

Comment: add opacity:1 to ul.ui-autocomplete class

Comment: Add `background-color` to `ul.ui-autocomplete`

Comment: Added `background-color` to ul.ui class its aworking now. @Morpheus